# How to retrieve data from firebase in a specific order?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Database sctucture image]

In my Flutter app, I want sorted data to depend upon the last date which is present in medicine list for a particular user, so how can I write my Firebase query?
I'm using Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (code has not yet been tested):

```
List<dynamic> getMedicinesSorted() async {
  final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users/tnzdrlpLD1hfJJ6o8iMV/MedicinesList')
    .get();

  final sorted = snapshot.docs.sort((docA, docB) => 
    new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(docA.data()['Last_Date']).compareTo(
      new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(docB.data()['Last_Date'])
    )
  );

  return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but i get one error on your code,i will add that error image please help me out if you have solution

Comment: You may be using an older version of `cloud_firestore`, so I think you should try using `snapshot.documents` instead of `snapshot.docs`. If you can, try to upgrade to the latest version of `cloud_firestore`.

Comment: which version you refer of cloud_fire store ,because i add latest version but error still there(the version is cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3)

Comment: @RiteshPatel I edited my answer to fix that `.docs` problem

Comment: thnk you it works now .....

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as correct if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6qy8.jpg